# Chrome inserts a DAPPlugin id into the page increasing the page length?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I am currently working on a site for a non profit [Getting to know Cancer](http://www.gettingtoknowcancer.org) and I was running into an odd issue. When I click on the form expand button on the right, Chrome inserts a large space at the end of the page as shown in the image below.
[image]

When I checked the code using F12 on Chrome ,i found that the additional space was due to some code Chrome inserts which is given below :

```
<embed type="application/x-dap-background" id="DAPPlugin" style="visibility: collapse">
```

I tested the site in IE,Firefox and Safari as well but I am getting this odd issue in Chrome only,any ideas on what might be causing it and how I can prevent it from happening ?

Comment: I'm guessing you have Download Accelerator Plus installed. http://www.speedbit.com/help/googlechrome.asp

Comment: I do but is there a way to prevent this from happening for chrome ,firefox and IE render it fine

Comment: remove the extension or get the extension developers to not embed the code.

Answer (score 5):

Put this on your stylesheet

```
#DAPPlugin{
display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I also got this problem!
but I notice that `id="DAPPlugin"`, then I try removing the DAP(download accelerator plus) in chrome extension.
Now, it works fine for me.